# ¿Cómo remover los espacios en blanco (' ') de un registro en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, split, concat

Necesito juntar el nombre de, por ejemplo, **un libro** a **unlibro**, si presenta uno o más espacios en blanco.

```
     Si ingreso        | espacios en blanco |       Resultado
-----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------
    EL RESPLANDOR      |          1         |      ELRESPLANDOR
CEMENTERIO DE ANIMALES |          2         | CEMENTERIODEANIMALES
        CARRIE         |          0         |        CARRIE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos puedes probar con `SELECT REPLACE`, puesto que veo en tus etiquetas usas MySQL

Por ejemplo en la consola de MySQL, declaro esta variable que contiene de manera intermedia 2 espacios

```
SET @titulo = "hola mundo JS";
```

Con SELECT REPLACE, necesitamos pasarle tres argumentos

1. Cadena que vamos a consultar para quitar espacios
2. Coincidencia a encontrar, en este caso un espacio en blanco así ' '
3. Sustitución del valor encontrado por otro, es decir por nada de espacio así ''

Finalmente nuestra consulta debería quedar

```
SELECT REPLACE(@titulo, ' ', '');
```

Resultado

```
+---------------------------+
| REPLACE(@titulo, ' ', '') |
+---------------------------+
| holamundoJS               |
+---------------------------+
```

Como puedes observar en el resultado aunque tenga espacios en blanco intermedios, se los quita al momento de hacer la consulta